# Knockoutjs custom button click action firing exponentially

Tags: typescript, knockout.js

I setup a button that has a custom binding handler which works great! However, I noticed that if I push the button the first time, it calls the action once, but if I push again, it calls the action 4 times, then 8 and so on until I refresh the page.

I've read a few of the other SO articles regarding knockoutjs button click events firing more than once, but I think my issue may be slightly different here.

Here's a gist of my complete setup:
https://gist.github.com/fischgeek/dcd6cad07bce920cbd03aa6d6dc1e125

TL;DR here's the custom binding handler taken out of context; maybe there's a glaring issue I'm not seeing

```
ko.bindingHandlers.actionButton = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context) {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            if (typeof value === 'object') {
                throw (`${value.Title()} binding must be a string.`);
            }
            var options = allBindingsAccessor().abOptions || {};
            $(element).attr('type', 'submit');
            $(element).addClass('btn');
            $(element).append(`<span data-bind="text: ${value}.Title()"></span>&nbsp;`);
            $(element).append(`<span class="glyphicon" data-bind="css: ${value}.Glyph()"></span>`);
            data[value].Title(options.Title || data[value].Title());
            ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { css: data[value].State(), click: data[value].WorkMethod() });
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context) {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { css: data[value].State(), click: data[value].WorkMethod() });
        }
    };
```

HTML usage:

```
<button data-bind="actionButton: 'abSaveSchedule', abOptions: {Title: 'Save Schedule'}"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the init method, you add a button and apply bindings to it. In the update method however (which is *also* called the first time *and* anytime any of the observables change), you apply the bindings to the element again.

This is why at every click the number of times the action is called increases by the number of observables updated multiplied by the number of bindings already applied to these observables (Title, Glyph, State??).

My guess is that this will function just fine by entirely removing the update handler.

Comment: I removed the update handler and the button does nothing. So, I put it back and removed the applyBindingsToNode call in the init. That allows the button to work, but still the same results with the increasing calls.

Answer (score 0):

This might be one of the *very rare* occasions you'll need knockout's `cleanNode`...

### On `init` and `update`

First of all, you'll have to know that after calling `init`, knockout will always call `update` as well. This means that your example will `applyBindings` to `element` *twice*, resulting in `WorkMethod` being called twice on click.

The logical fix, like the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45994162/3297291) by [Philip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4300023/philip-bijker) suggests, is to remove the `applyBindings` call in the `update` method. This will fix most of your issues, but you will still lack something else: automatic updates upon changing `Title`, `State` or `WorkMethod`. If this isn't a problem, I'd suggest not making these properties `observable`. But since they *are* `observable`, I'll assume they're meant to be updated...

### Making sure the view stays up-to-date

Let me explain why your binding lacks "update support":

In the `init` method, you `unwrap` `Title`, `State` and `WorkMethod` *before* applying the inner bindings. This means your custom binding will get all the `update` calls, which in turn means you'll have to handle re-applying bindings to the inner elements. (Have a look at the `if` and `with` bindings' source for reference)

For the `text` and `css` bindings, the solution is to pass the reference to the `observable` rather than the inner value. This makes the default bindings handle updates in their own `update` methods.

```
$(element).append(`<span data-bind="text: ${value}.Title"></span>&nbsp;`);
// ...
ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, {
  css: data[valueAccessor()].State
// ...
```

For the `click` binding, we'll have to resort to "reapplying" the bindings, because it [doesn't unwrap its valueAccessor...](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/241c26ca82e6e4b3eaee39e3dc0a92f85bc1df0c/src/binding/defaultBindings/event.js#L23) (Anyone else feels like this should be changed?)

To prevent attaching multiple onClicks, you'll need to clean the node before re-applying bindings.

### Example with "just the fixes"

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.actionButton = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context) {
    var value = valueAccessor();

    if (typeof value === 'object') {
      throw (`${value.Title()} binding must be a string.`);
    }
    var options = allBindingsAccessor().abOptions || {};
    $(element).attr('type', 'submit');
    $(element).addClass('btn');

    // Keep the observable, but allow for it to be set from
    // the binding's options
    if (options.Title) {
      data[value].Title(options.Title);
    }
    
    $(element).append(`<span data-bind="text: ${value}.Title"></span>&nbsp;`);
    $(element).append(`<span class="glyphicon" data-bind="css: ${value}.Glyph"></span>`);

    
    
  }, update:  function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context) {
    ko.cleanNode(element);
    ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, {
      css: data[valueAccessor()].State,
      click: data[valueAccessor()].WorkMethod()
    });
  }
};


var vm = {

  Title: ko.observable("title"),
  State: ko.observable(""),
  WorkMethod: ko.observable(
    function() {
      console.log("click");
    }
  ),
  Glyph: ko.observable("")
};

ko.applyBindings({
  "abSaveSchedule": vm,
  changeMethod: () => vm.WorkMethod(() => console.log("click2")),
  changeTitle: () => vm.Title("New title")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<button data-bind="actionButton: 'abSaveSchedule', abOptions: { Title: 'override title' }"></button>

<button data-bind="click: changeMethod">change work method</button>
<button data-bind="click: changeTitle">change title</button>
```

Now, even though this "works", it's a bit cluttered.

### Refactored

Here's a rewrite that does the same and, in my opinion, is easier to read:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.actionButton = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context) {
    var propName = valueAccessor();
    var options = allBindingsAccessor().abOptions || {};
    var ctx = data[propName];

    if (options.Title) {
      data[propName].Title(options.Title);
    }

    ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, {
      attr: {
        "type": "submit",
        "class": "btn"
      },
      css: ctx.State,
      click: (...args) => ctx.WorkMethod()(...args),
      template: {
        data: ctx,
        nodes: $(`<span data-bind="text:Title"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon" data-bind="css: Glyph"></span>`)
      }
    });
    return {
      controlsDescendantBindings: true
    };
  }
};


var vm = {

  Title: ko.observable("title"),
  State: ko.observable(""),
  WorkMethod: ko.observable(
    function() {
      console.log("click");
    }
  ),
  Glyph: ko.observable("")
};

ko.applyBindings({
  "abSaveSchedule": vm,
  changeMethod: () => vm.WorkMethod(() => console.log("click2")),
  changeTitle: () => vm.Title("New title")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<button data-bind="actionButton: 'abSaveSchedule', abOptions: { Title: 'override title' }"></button>

<button data-bind="click: changeMethod">change work method</button>
<button data-bind="click: changeTitle">change title</button>
```